# Wrong C# compiler error message on async lambda type inference

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I bumped into this C# compiler error and while I'm ok with the compiler not being able to infer the type of the lambda the error message seems wrong. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
Func<object> lambda = async () => { return await Task.FromResult(1); };
```

and here's the compiler error:

> error CS4010: Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type '`System.Func<object>`'. An async lambda expression may return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to '`System.Func<object>`'.

The part I don't quite understand is the last sentence. The lambda is indeed returning `Task<int>`, but why does the compiler think that it should try to convert it to `System.Func<object>`?

On the other hand, if what the error message is trying to convey is that `System.Func<Task<int>>` cannot be assigned to `System.Func<object>`, that doesn't seem to be the case thanks to generic delegate covariance which means that this works just fine instead:

```
Func<object> lambda = new Func<Task<int>>(async () => { return await Task.FromResult(1); });
```

Comment: The compiler things it should convert it to a `System.Func<object>` because that is how you have declared the variable and it is not compatible with an async delegate.

Comment: *The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The lambda is indeed returning `Task<int>`, but why does the compiler think that it should try to convert it to `System.Func<object>`?

I believe the error message is poorly worded. It's trying to derive a return type for the lambda (which can be `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>`), and convert *the lambda* to `Func<object>`. I recommend that you raise an issue on Microsoft Connect requesting a clearer error message.

> On the other hand, if what the error message is trying to convey is that `System.Func<Task<int>>` cannot be assigned to `System.Func<object>`, that doesn't seem to be the case thanks to generic delegate covariance

True, but the compiler doesn't determine the type of lambda expressions until "later" than most expressions. The compiler doesn't see `Func<Task<int>>` (it just sees a lambda expression taking no arguments and returning `Task` or `Task<int>`), and so it won't use generic delegate variance.

I'm hoping that Eric Lippert will do a blog post on how `async` lambda expressions are resolved, particularly in the case of method overload selection.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, the misleading error message is exactly what I was concerned with. Just wanted to have some quick feedback before reporting it, which I just did [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770315/wrong-c-compiler-error-message-on-async-lambda-type-inference).